# SQL Server Views insert update

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a table in SQL server that I want to insert/update into another table using a view.

Table A is the Source Table, Table B is the target. I want to bring over all new records and any that has been updated. Is this possible using a view and if so how?

Create view Integration As
Select * from Table_A

The above will give me all records which is fine but I dont want to bring over the table everyday and I want to design logic around table B.  I only want the records that are new and or have been updated. Table A does not have a created Date. The table Structure is like the below.

People, location, Payor

Bob, 2A, MA

Comment: How do you define "new and or have been updated"?  That definition can be included as a `WHERE` clause in your view.

Comment: Ahh correct. On Table A there is no create date. it gives information like, ID, Name, Location.

Comment: If you would provide some detailed logic over there and some sample data, it would help us to help you.

Comment: I updated my question to provide as much detail as I can.

Comment: Not sure I fully understood what you're trying to achieve either. Tables A and B are two separated tables having the same structure ? You want to fill table B on a punctual basis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve or why.

Surely Table_B IS Table_A because Table_A includes all records that have been created (i.e. "new") or updated.

If there is a timestamp on Table_A which holds the created or updated date for each record and you only wanted records created or updated after a certain timestamp you could create a view to do this.  You could even use current server time minus some arbitrary figure if you wanted the data in the view to roll forward.

You need to include more information about the contents of Table_A and what you hope that the data in the view will achieve to get a more concise answer.

Comment: unfortunately, the table does not have a create/modified date and is a Vendor's Table. That was my first thought. My second was a trigger however it is a managed package.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  If it's so log changes to the table so you can see a snapshot of what's changed then you probably want to add a trigger to log updated and inserts to some kind of witness table but if you have lots of transactions on the table, this log may become quite large quite quickly.

Comment: What would the view be like if I could find created date and modified date.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM Table_A
WHERE LastModifiedDate > '2014-12-31 23:59:59'

would bring back everything from this year.  Using the GET_DATE() command would let you modify it so it rolls with system date